# How to apply CSS to part of some text without breaking the text content itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am currently considering how to support a legacy web application in a new language(language here meaning spoken language - not code!).

I will be doing this using some form of javascript internationalisation library however I've stumbled upon an issue.

Currently the application can be driven solely by keyboard shortcuts - these short cuts are indicated to the user by underlining the letter of a function label on the screen which corresponds with a short cut.

For example:

```
<u>R</u>un
<u>J</u>ump
J<u>o</u>g
```

The problem is when these strings are replaced with tokens for internationalisation the strings are going to be stored as plain text and I would like to not have to tarnish these strings files with html tags(especially a  tag which is discouraged nowadays anyway)

If we decouple logic to decide  which letter to underline - which could well change with along with a language change - how could I go about underlining a single character in a string? Is it even possible?

```
//HTML
<a href="#" id="jump" data-i18n="action.jump"></a>

//Strings file
action.jump=Jump

//Javascript/JQuery
$('<someHowOnlySelectAParticularLetter('J')> #jump').css({text-decoration:overline});

function someHowOnlySelectAParticularLetter(var character){
   //TODO
}
```

Thanks in advance for any responses - even I haven't explained the issue at hand clearly please say so and I will attempt to clarify any questions!

Comment: The big question for you is how do you intend to determine which letter to underline? You could potentially underline the same letter if you use the same position.

Comment: I usually don't recommend libraries as a solution, but you might want to look at [LetteringJS](http://letteringjs.com/) at least for some ideas; it's pretty simple code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep using that design, you're gonna run into all sorts of problems.

- What if the translated word doesn't have the letter shortcut you applied to your other language?
- If a user gets used to a set of shortcuts and changes the language, are all the shortcuts he is used to going to change?

For example, Ctrl+S is a widely used shortcut for Save, even if some languages don't have a S in their translation of 'Save'. Change that letter to W, which is the common shortcut for Quit, and you're in for an unpleasant user experience.

I suggest you change your markup to

```
(R) Run
(J) Jump
(O) Jog
```

That way you only need to translate the word part, and leave the shortcut as it is.

Comment: I accepted this as the correct answer as this is what I am going to go with - thanks for your suggestion - I should have noticed something "smelled" wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What letter is "active" is language-dependent, so this info has to be stored in each language specific config file (translation table file):

```
English:
RUN: "Run"
RUN_ACTION: "R"

French:
RUN: "Courir"
RUN_ACTION: "C"
```

Then use this information (and meta-infromation) to generate your HTML:

```
function buildAction(label, letter) {
    return label.replace(letter, '<u id="action-' + letter + '">' + letter + '</u>');
}

var html = '<p>menu: ' + buildAction(RUN, RUN_ACTION) + ', ...</p>';
document.write(html);
```

Then you can `$('#action-' + RUN_ACTION).css` and `$('#action-' + RUN_ACTION).click`.

With this you only need to switch between translation table files.

I'd generate the HTML server-side though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

I wasn't sure whether to mark this response as the answer or @Gael's as the correct answer.

If someone comes along in the future in the and needs to implement this logic for the right reasons(unlike mine) I'd recommend your solution!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would have to use a little bit of RegEx (regular expressions) and .split to be able to grab that letter, store it in a variable and then style it with jquery's .css method.

Comment: It sounds good, but some more explanations on the RegEx part and styling a letter with jQuery's `css()` method would be nice.

Comment: How does RegEx apply to selecting a letter with CSS?

Comment: You don't select it with CSS. You point your regex at the HTML element that holds the letter that you are wanting to select.

Answer (score 0):

It is an admirable goal to separate data from presentation.

I don't think pure CSS will get you all the way there, without also having some supporting HTML markup.

You actually need the hotkey information in two places:

1. In the UI markup
2. In the code that processes key presses

I would suggest that you store the information about the hotkey in a format similar to:

```
// Word       Hotkey    Offset    Function    Language
// Sichern    S         0         Save        DE
// Springe    p         1         Jump        DE
```

(example above uses German).

Use that data to drive

1. Rendering of the UI (e.g. when rendering to HTML markup, wrap the character position designated by Offset with a tag of your choice that matches your CSS rules.
2. Have the code that captures key clicks and executes functionality use the same data.